# What is best way to generate Sitemap.xml in Content delivery server(NON SXA)

Tags: events, sitemap

Currently, we are generating `Sitemap.xml` on the Publishing end event (`publish:end:remote`), this event takes some time to complete Publishing and this is causing the slowness. We using the `Sitecore 9.0.1` Sitecore instance.

Here scheduler won't work as we need to create `.xml` on the cd server.

Could you please suggest any best way we can generate a sitemap on the CD server?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to resolve the Sitemap generation:

1. You could create a Sitecore `Scheduled Task` that will go through all the pages under `Home` node. Each of the page templates could have a `include in sitemap` checkbox. You can run this job every 4 hours or even daily based on the need. Store the XML generated in Media Library or in the file system.
2. Another option would be to have a `Sitecore Controller Rendering`. This would work at runtime, only affect the Sitemap.xml page and might be slow for first time load. Once the XML is generated, you could store it in the IIS cache and have a config setting to clear it every 4 hours.

My recommendation would be the first one.

Comment: regarding to your first option ,if we create scheduler will work in cm servers only what about cd server ?

Comment: We have scheduled task implemented that writes xml to sitecore field and publishes it to web database, thus it's available on CD instance too.

Comment: Yes, you may also write it to Media Library and publish it as part of the job itself. Then it again it can be available in CD

Answer (score 0):

`publish:end:remote` event handlers are called asynchronously. Content Management server does not wait for them to complete before publishing is completed.

Maybe you  have `publish:end` event handler as well? which is fired directly at the end of publishing?

I don't think that there is one correct answer to your question - it all depends of number of items, time of sitemap generation, frequency of publishing and other factors.

You should really check though if every publish action your content authors execute is a reason to generate new sitemap.

Comment: we have publish:end event as well

Comment: You don't need sitemap on CM server. Get rid of that event